# Bootstrap modal. Catch Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modalmanager'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I get a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modalmanager'
```

In my script.js file I have:

```
$('#addShoplistModal').modal('toggle');
```

Code of my jsp page:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id='addShoplistModal'>
<div class='modal-header'>
    <a class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>×</a>
    <h3>Add Shopitem</h3>
</div>

<div class='modal-body'>
    <form id="addShopitemForm">
        <div id="name-error"></div>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <div id="quantity-error"></div> 
        <input type="text" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class='modal-footer'>
    <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a> 

        <a shoplistId="" id="add-shoplist" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="<spring:url value="/web/js/jquery-2.0.0.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<spring:url value="/web/js/jquery.validate.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<spring:url value="/web/js/bootstrap.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<spring:url value="/web/js/bootstrap-modal.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<spring:url value="/web/js/script.js" />"></script>
```

The error is at bootstrap-modal.js at

```
manager = manager.appendModal ?
            manager : $(manager).modalmanager().data('modalmanager');
```

Tell me, please, how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you including `bootstrap.js` **and** `bootstrap-modal.js`? Also, I'm not 100% sure jQuery 2.0 works with bootstrap

Comment: I thought that bootstrap.js doesn't include modals. I removed bootstrap-modal.js and all works. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bootstrap.js` file *should* contain all Bootstrap JavaScript features, such as the modal. Therefore, it's not necessary, and obviously breaks things, when you try to include the modal feature library a second time. Just remove `bootstrap-modal.js`.

Comment: Stumbled across this looking for something else. Just for future reference, bootstrap-modal is an extension of the modal functionality baked in to core bootstrap, so it is a separate thing. 
https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal.
Since I experienced something similar I'd say chances are A.Zayats encountered the error by loading the js files in the wrong order, loading jquery a second time, or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue once. Check if you have added jQuery twice. If yes, remove the second jquery. It should work fine.